# W2ui grid Return custom error mesage isted of data from remote url

Tags: javascript, w2ui

I'm using W2ui grid version 2 and trying to return an custom error message instead of record data.

The JSON I'm sending back to grid is

```
{error:true, message:"Test"}
```

but grid is not showing my message instead it is showing "HTTP error. See console for more details." in message poup. How can I change this message?